# PowerShell module for handling Visual Studio Object Model from within NuGet Install.ps1/Uninstall.ps1 scripts

Tags: visual-studio-2010, powershell, nuget

I'm trying to create a NuGet package that contains both managed (assemblies) and unmanaged (native DLLs) binaries, and also support several platforms (x86, x64).

To have a better understanding of how to handle that properly, I had a look at several packages that share similar requirements, published on the official [nuget feed](http://nuget.org/). One of them is [Microsoft.SQLServer.Compact](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.Compact).

Seeing what is done in the **Install.ps1**, **Uninstall.ps1** PowerShell scripts and in the **VS.psm1** PowerShell module is very helpful.

The VS.psm1 module contains definitions for a few functions allowing to control Visual Studio from within the package installation script (notably, through the $dte object). These functions are based on the [Visual Studio Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/za2b25t3%28v=VS.71%29.aspx), which I don't know yet and that is (in my opinion) not very well documented.

I was wondering if you know about a PowerShell module that would allow to easily handle the Visual Studio Object model from a NuGet PowerShell script. Alternatively, any pointer to books, blog posts, articles, ... showing a few examples about how to properly use that object model from PowerShell would be very welcome. The only examples I have found on the net usually illustrate very basic functionality.

Also, if you know about other NuGet packages dealing with both managed and unmanaged libraries that I could use as examples, that would be nice.

I could of course start from what I have seen in the files mentioned above and roll my own module, but I would rather concentrate on my package itself if there is already something available.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [StudioShell](http://studioshell.codeplex.com/).  It is a system for bringing PowerShell automation into VS.NET and is available as an installer but also as a NuGet package to enable the sort of scenario you describe.  PluralSight course "Everyday PowerShell for Developers" course has an intro to the system and there are some examples on the project site.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be directly related to your post.  The Package Manager Console in my opinion should be called the PowerShell Console.  It gives you full access to the DTE.

I have a trivial example of using it, pure PowerShell, no t4 or extensions, to add several files to Visual Studio to automate adding Command Pattern classes.

http://github.com/jefflomax/vs-package-manager-console-cmdlets

We could certainly use a more complete library of PowerShell cmdlets to handle simple Visual Studio tasks in this environment.