# Adding project to solution through command line

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I have a Visual studio solution that is made up of multiple test projects. Each project is a copy of a template project. When the template project is copied there is a batch script that is ran that does some file renamings and adds a couple other specified files. What i would like to do is then have the project added to the solution during that process. I was looking at devenv switches [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee0c8y7%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) on MSDN but i am not seeing anything about adding a project to a solution.

Is adding a project to a solution possible through the command line?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't mind writing a bit of PowerShell, you can do this pretty easily. First, read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14440049/powershell-module-for-handling-visual-studio-object-model-from-within-nuget-inst) and its answers. You'll find a pointer to a nuget package (Microsoft.SQLServer.Compact) which includes PowerShell scripts to automate VS through its object model. This is a good place to start to have some examples of how to handle a solution file from PowerShell. Then you write a small PowerShell script using the [SolutionFolder.AddFromFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte80.solutionfolder.addfromfile) to add your project to your solution. This might be even easier using [StudioShell](http://studioshell.codeplex.com/) and its provider, but I haven't tried it yet.

Answer (score 6):

If you are here after 2019 and using Asp.Net Core. Here is the way to do it:

```
dotnet sln yoursolution.sln add yourprojectpath/yourproject.csproj
```

Answer (score -1):

For sln file try [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/414309/generate-solution-file-from-list-of-csproj). For project file you can run some xslt or any other necessary transform to edit. For example you can create MSBuild proj file to run xslt transform over desired sln file and then run it in cmd like: MSBuild.exe MyProj.proj. The sample content of MyProj.proj is like:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Target Name="Transform">
    <TransformXml Source="Project.csproj" Transform="Transform.xml" Destination="New_Project.csproj" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Comment: I think i am confused on something. The project file is an XML file. I get that. The solution file is not. So how does calling MSbuild on a project add it to the solution?

Comment: Sorry, you are right. [Look at this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/414309/generate-solution-file-from-list-of-csproj). Any way the sln is a text one, and you can add some content you need.